# Spring Boot standalone jar crashing when config location is a Windows absolute path

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I built an application that depends on Spring Boot. As we are near to deploying it, I started testing the application outside of Eclipse and Gradle. This is where we ran into a crashing issue with in the early life-cycle of Spring Boot. The application runs fine within Eclipse and with `gradlew run`. However, it has problems with `java -jar <App>.jar`.

The following is the exception that I am getting.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:494)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:176)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.getResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:63)
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.exists(ClassPathResource.java:138)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.isFile(PropertySourcesLoader.java:88)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:74)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:295)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:283)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addProperySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:135)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:92)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:275)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:880)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:869)
        at hello.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:18)
        ... 6 more
```

We are using Spring Boot 1.0.0.RC4. To isolate the problem, I copied the code from the tutorial (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start) and started a new Eclipse Gradle project. There is only one class file. It is pretty standard, except that I replaced `@Controller` with `@RestController` and removed `@ResponseBody`. Because that is what my application uses.

Hello.java.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a pretty standard `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies { classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC4') }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies { compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.0.RC4' }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.11' }
```

With this test hello application, I did `gradlew clean build` and then tried `java -jar Hello.jar`. Imagine my surprise when I received the same exception as above. Maybe I'm still missing something, but this outcome seems to indicate that there is perhaps a problem with Spring Boot?

I would greatly appreciate a solution ... any solution (even if it is a dirty workaround).

**EDIT 1:**

As requested, the machine I'm testing the standalone jar is on Windows (8.1).

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT 2:**

As requested, I also tested the `spring-boot-sample-web-ui`. The same exception still occurs.

**EDIT 3:** Salutations to @DaveSyer

I may have discovered a potential cause. The environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` seems to be causing the exception. When it is not set, the test `Hello` application and the `spring-boot-sample-web-ui` application worked as intended.

**EDIT 4:**

For anyone else interested, I've uploaded the test application to GitHub (https://github.com/ChrisZhong/spring-boot-jar-sample)

Comment: Are you, perhaps, running with a different version of Java in the command line "java -jar ..."? (I can see that throws clause in the source code of my Java 1.6 and 1.7 JDKs but the line number doesn't match.)

Comment: @DaveSyer, this is what I get when I do `java -version`. `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)`

Comment: I posted an answer in response (formatting is better that way). If you can test the sample, and also post a complete project to reproduce that will help.

Comment: BTW you don't need to provide the version number in dependencies that Boot knows about (in its parent pom).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but if someone ran into the same issue with the SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION setting on Windows:

To set the path to the application.properties (or any other name) you should use this command

```
set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:C:/path/application.properties
```

(mind the missing double slash after "file:")
You can also set this path into the Windows environment variables. This setting was successfully tested with Spring boot 1.1.2. It may also works for older releases.

If you write instead

```
set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=C:/path/application.properties
```

Spring boot won't lookup the properties file and ignores it's settings.

Or if you write

```
set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file://C:/path/application.properties
```

Spring boot will throw an UnknownHostException for the drive letter "C".

Answer (score 1):

RESOLUTION: You have a (Windows) absolute file path in `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` environment variable, so Boot is trying to resolve that as a classpath resource and failing. The fix is to use a "file://" prefix for any config location that is a file (not on the classpath).

The exception is cryptic and shouldn't really be necessary, so I raised a ticket to get that fixed as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/486

ORIGINAL: Works for me:

```
$ cd spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui
$ gvm use gradle 1.9
$ gradle clean build
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
$ java -jar build/libs/*.jar
...
<happy app>
```

Comment: Just tried it. I'm testing this on Windows. So there is no GVM. But I downloaded Gradle 1.9, used that version and tried running it. Same type of exception.

Comment: Works for me on Windows too (took all morning to get a VM set up, phew!). Oracle JDK 1.7.0_51 and gradle 1.11. Are you sure your JDK is kosher (that line number)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "JDK is kosher (that line number)". Would you enlighten me?

Comment: since it worked on your Windows, I looked deeper into the issue and may have discovered the cause. I have the environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=%UserProfile%\application.properties` set. Unsetting it seems to resolve the issue. However, that variable needs to be set as it centralizes the properties file for all applications.

Comment: The "kosher" question was just "are you sure your JDK is what you think it is?" (the line numbers in the stack traces don't match mine).

Comment: Is `%UserProfile%` not resolved by the operating system? I imagine that could cause issues. Wouldn't it be the same in the IDE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49590/discussion-between-chris-and-dave-syer)